# How to get the Config.json file for Alexa voice service (AVS) SDK (Download button missing ?)

Tags: android, alexa-voice-service, alexa-skills-kit

I am trying to build AVS built-in device for Android platform

I followed the steps given in this doc

https://developer.amazon.com/en-GB/docs/alexa/avs-device-sdk/android.html

According to the steps given in the above doc, after i register my device, i should get the config.json file downloaded
which is required in the below step

```
bash setup.sh config.json -a androidConfig.txt -s 998987
```

But i din't find any download button for the Config.json, neither it was downloaded automatically after saving the device.

Not sure if i am missing anything here or any other way to get this.
If any one has the way of it please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

first please create `config.json` file also add

```
{
 "deviceInfo": {
  "clientId": "your clientid",
  "productId": "your product id"
 }
}
```

then try with `bash setup.sh config.json -a androidConfig.txt -s 998987`

Answer (score 0):

You would need to register [a product in AVS](https://developer.amazon.com/alexa/console/avs/products)

After fulfilling the product details, go to `Security Profile`.

Under it, choose the `Other devices and platforms`, and put in your desired Client ID name. From there, click the `GENERATE ID`